# What is a trivial $G$-bundle exactly?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles

Let a fiber bundle be given by a structure $(E,B,\pi, F)$. It is a G-bundle if it is equipped with a *maximal* $G$-Atlas, i.e. a set of local trivialization charts such that transition maps on their intersections are continuous ([wiki definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_bundle#Structure_groups_and_transition_functions) of $G$-Atlas). What does it mean exactly for it to be *trivial*? Surely, there must exist a trivialization chart of the whole base space $(B, \phi_i)$, but I'm not sure that every $G$-Atlas must contain such a chart. Is it included in the definition that an atlas of a *trivial* $G$-bundle includes such a chart? Or can we perhaps prove that every *maximal* $G$-Atlas includes a base space trivialization chart if it is known that the projection $\pi$ is trivial (i.e. that a base space trivialization chart is possible)? If so, I'd like to know how to prove it.

Comment: Your post kind of wanders around and it's not entirely clear what you are asking. Do you want to know the *definition* of a trivial $G$-bundle? Do you already know some definition but you want to know the *meaning* of that definition? If the latter, please edit your post to include the definition you are working from.

Comment: @LeeMosher In fact, I don't know the definition of a *trivial* G-bundle. I only guessed what it can be. But I am certainly more interested in the *meaning* of it. I removed the *definition* tag

Comment: Well, the *meaning* is that the bundle is equivalent to the product bundle $B \times F$ in which the $G$ action is induced by the given action of $G$ on $F$. One might even take that to be the definition; one can then try to deduce some property of the maximal atlas which is equivalent to that definition.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks, but I'm not yet familiar with the notion of bundle equivalence. I can certainly look it up, but even then it doesn't seem it would answer my question concerning the presence of a base space chart in every *maximal* G-Atlas. If it is possible to deduce, then I don't have any more questions.

Comment: In that case the most useful thing I can think of to say any further is to first learn about bundle equivalence, and then take what I suggested in my previous comment as an exercise. Perhaps your notion of a certain base space chart would lead to a good solution to that exercise.